# Is there an open-source iOS screen viewer/ recorder for macOS?

Tags: macos, ios, software-recommendation, screen-capture

Requirements:

- better than QuickTime movie recording: it doesn't pass the sound through
- Wormhole and is great but that is a paid closed source software
- Open source strongly preferred

Is there a open source software which would let me view my iOS screen on macOS?

Comment: Feel free to drop in specific bugs. I refactored this so it reads like the great recommendation question with clear requirements that it is.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at [videosnap](https://github.com/matthutchinson/videosnap). It is an free and open source utility that allows you to record the screen of your iOS device from a Mac.

Note that it is a command line utility you can use from the Terminal - it does not have a graphical user interface.

Comment: I've tried this, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I tried on Big Sur, on both M1 and Intel macs.

Comment: I haven’t tried it on Big Sur - have you tried giving it Permissions in Settings / Security & Privacy?

Comment: Hi,

I am aware that you are not qualified for this program and have only made one suggestion, but if you have the competence I would love to ask a safety question.

The app requests the camera and the microphone, which must be configured in the system settings. Not the app itself but the terminal because it is a CLI program.

Isn't there a risk that malware can use the CLI to gain immediate access to the camera and microphone?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you give permissions to Terminal.app those permissions only apply to that programs and programs started from there. You're not giving out permissions to "CLI" in general (whatever that would mean (and yes, I know what CLI stands for)). I.e. a malware program cannot then just start a "CLI" program and gain permissions that way - it would need to actually start the Terminal.app and instruct it to run that "CLI" program. So that turns it into a more generic question, than just about videosnap.

Answer (score -3):

If you wish to remotely view and control another device (doesn't matter what sort of device or brand) I would recommend Windows Remote Desktop. Surprisingly (by its name) it doesn't only work on Windows but also works on macOS as well. All you need to do (after you download it off the App Store) is to open the program, click 'Add A Device', type in the IP address of the device you wish to view and/or control, set all the settings to your desire, click 'set' or something similar (which will bring you back to the main menu), and double-click on the device which you wish to view and/or control and it will then connect.
Note: you will be needed to be connected to the internet the entire time you wish to view/control the selected device.

Here is a walk-through on how to download and use Windows Remote Desktop:
WALKTHROUGH FOR HOW TO DOWNLOAD - https://youtu.be/3pVtdtpNMGE
WALKTHROUGH FOR HOW TO SET UP AND USE - https://youtu.be/dJNwdJLPDS8

Comment: How does Windows Remote Desktop send iOS screen data to a Mac?

Comment: with Windows Remote Desktop you can *veiw* and/or control other devices - you can VEIW other devices

Comment: Aah. So then you just need to find a question asking how to view windows from iOS and not the other way around. The direction of sharing here is the opposite of what you describe.

Comment: Windows Remote Desktop also works on macOS and probably iOS as well

Comment: Can you add detailled steps on how to enable Remote Desktop to remotely access iOS devices, and how to use this then in the context of the question?

Comment: I'll make a screen recording, put it on YouTube and put the link in here. It will show how to install and set up Windows Remote Desktop so that you can see the screen of your iOS like you wanted. Won't be long.

Comment: there, done. The links are in and are now valid.

Answer (score -3):

If you wish to record what is currently on your screen, the easiest way on a macOS is to press Comand, Shift, 5. This will bring you to a small menu in which you can screen record or take screenshots with heaps of different options. on the bottom of the screen will be where the small menu is. Simply hover the cursor over the options to see what they do. One will say 'Screen Reccord' or something similar. Click on this option and a small countdown may start (depending on the settings in 'Options') and after the countdown, it will start recording your screen - if there is no countdown it will instantly start recording - and press the stop button on the very top of your screen (where it will show the time and battery and other things) and it will save it to the desktop unless the 'Options' settings were changed.

Comment: Sorry to be negative, but this also doesn’t seem to attempt to address iOS screens being viewable from a Mac. An edit might be needed to make this apply to this question.

Comment: with Windows Remote Desktop, you can easily view what is on the screen of a different device such as an iOS or any other device